# unicurses' addstr() interferes with time.sleep()

Tags: python-3.6, sleep, curses, python-curses

The `time.sleep()` delay will sleep before `addstr()` in the script below

```
from unicurses import *
from time import *
stdscr = initscr()
addstr("Hello")
sleep(1)
endwin()
```

Is there any `curses` function for delays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`napms`](https://github.com/Chiel92/unicurses/blob/master/unicurses/__init__.py#L1879) rather than `sleep`.  It works with [other](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.napms) python/curses bindings.

The example

```
from unicurses import *
from time import *
stdscr = initscr()
addstr("Hello")
sleep(1)
endwin()
```

looks odd, since there is no explicit [**`refresh`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.refresh) call in [endwin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.endwin).  Something like this might work for you:

```
from unicurses import *
from time import *
stdscr = initscr()
addstr("Hello")
refresh()
napms(1000)
endwin()
```

Comment: hmm it still does the same thing